# Suppose $X$,$Y$ are sets, $A,B ⊆ X$ and $C,D ⊆ Y$. Compare $(A \times B) − (C \times D)$ with $((A − C) \times B) ∪ (A \times (B − D))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a bit puzzled by this question. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ and $C$ and $D$ are subsets of $Y$, is it safe to assume that the elements of $A$ and $B$ are completely different from those of $C$ and $D$? I feel like that's too simple and not a good assumption to make. If that were the case, then $(B − D)$ would simply be $B$. This would certainly make the comparison much easier, but I don't have any reason as to why this assumption might be made.

Does anyone have any insight on how to compare these two arbitrary sets?

Answer (score 0):

If $(x,y)$ is in $((A-C) \times B) \cup (A \times (B-D))$, if in the LHS, then $x \in A, x \notin C, y \in B$ and then $(x,y) \in A \times B$ and $(x,y) \notin C \times D$... The same can be said when it is in the RHS (check this..).

This shows at least one inclusion. The other also holds:

Now if $(x,y) \in (A \times B) - (C \times D)$, we know $x \in A, y \in B$ and $x\notin C$ *or* $y \notin D$. What can you say about these two last cases?

Comment: I'm still very confused here. I'm having trouble following your train of thought. Does LHS refer to that which is to the left of the word 'with' or the left side of the union symbol? And I understand the statements you are making about the sets in which x and y reside, but I do not understand how you got to them.

Comment: @Nick of the union. What exactly cannot you follow?

Comment: I just don’t know what the conclusion will be. I am especially confused that you never mentioned the sets X and Y. Do they not matter in the comparison?

Comment: The only conclusion I can think is maybe RHS of the ‘with’ ends up being (A×B) ∪ (A×B) which is a subset of of the LHS??

Comment: Because for both sides, x is in A, y is in B, x is NOT in C, and y is NOT in D

Comment: @Nick $X$ and$Y$  are not really relevant. The conclusion will be equality of sets.

Comment: @Nick If $(x,y) \notin C \times D$ this means that $x \notin C$ **or** $y \notin D$. Not and. It's a negation of an and-statement hence an or-statement.